# Handling mouse and touch events

Tags: .net, wpf, touch

is there a way to handle touchup and touchdown events exact the same way like mouseup and mousedown?
If I do a press with one finger then windows want to do a left mouse button click to show a contextmenu. The mousedown event is not fired.
Are there events to simply react to touchdown and touchup like mosueup and mousedown? In Win32 there were the pointer-events which works as expected.

Comment: See [Input Overview - Touch and Manipulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/input-overview#touch-and-manipulation).

Comment: I tried it with IsManipulationEnabled and ManipulationStarting and ManipulationComplete events, but I never get the starting alone to react on the touchdown.

Comment: I only get the messages if I put the finger off the screen - not on press.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it!
You must set `Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled` to false to get the TouchDown event when pressing the finger (without lifting it).