# WPF Application does not receive any touch or stylus events

Tags: wpf, touch, touch-event

I'm working on an .NET 5.0 / .NET Framework 4.8 application, where I don't receive any touch nor stylus events. Even all mouse events (triggered by touch) doesn't have an `StylusDevice` in it's `MouseEventArgs`. Each touch event seems to be translated immediately into some mouse event and I have no idea where or how.

I was trying to reproduce the behavior in an smaller application to share, but I was not able to achieve it.

So rather than asking for "Where are my touch events going?" (without beeing able to provide code), I would like to have some suggestions, where I can try to trace these kind of events to get an idea what is blocking / translating them.

I already use [SnoopWPF](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) and while I will find touch events in the application I tried to reproduce, but not a single touch / stylus / manipulation is triggered on the actually application.

Had someone experienced something similar in the past or knows tools to get more information about it?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/47219740/1136211

Comment: @Clemens Thank you. I haven't seen this so far, but unfortunately nothing changed :-( I set this on the mainwindow of the application and still don't get the touch events triggered.

Comment: I have the same issue after installing .net 4.8 on our system. Im also trying to figure out why this happens...